# Mongodb aggreate, cannot get sort to work on date field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Data:

```
{ 
  "properties" : { 
    "user" : ObjectId("51d3053627f4169a52000005"), 
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2013-07-02T18:00:03.841Z")
  }, 
  "_id" : ObjectId("51d31a87716fb81a58000003"), 
  "geometry" : { 
    "type" : "Point", 
    "coordinates" : [ 10, 10 ] 
  } 
},{ 
  "properties" : { 
    "user" : ObjectId("51d3053627f4169a52000005"), 
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2013-07-02T18:23:03.841Z")
  }, 
  "_id" : ObjectId("51d31a87716fb81a58000003"), 
  "geometry" : { 
    "type" : "Point", 
    "coordinates" : [ 20, 20 ] 
  } 
}
```

And I am trying the following query:

```
db.locations.aggregate(
  { $group: { 
    _id: "$properties.user", 
    locations: { 
      $push: {
        location: {geometry: "$geometry", properties: "$properties"} 
      } 
    }
  }}, 
  { $sort: { "properties.createdOn": 1 }}
);
```

No matter which direction I change the sort flag (1/-1) the order of my results does not change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the `$group`, your pipeline docs only contain those fields defined in the `$group`, so `properties.createdOn` doesn't exist for the `$sort` operation.

Move your `$sort` before the `$group` in the pipeline instead:

```
db.locations.aggregate(
  { $sort: { "properties.createdOn": 1 }},
  { $group: { 
    _id: "$properties.user", 
    locations: { 
      $push: {
        location: {geometry: "$geometry", properties: "$properties"} 
      } 
    }
  }}
);
```

Comment: Perfect, was having the same problem w/ limit as well.  Doing sort, limit, group works perfectly.  Thanks again @JohnnyHK